# Efficiently converting data.table columns from numerical to character

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I'm looking through some legacy R code, which loads a text file into an R data.table, and then converts the column type from type numeric to character.

Here is how the author did this:

```
library(data.table)
dtable = read.table("path/filename.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t",check.names=FALSE)

for(i in c(1,2,3,8:18))
{
dtable[,i] <- as.character(as.vector(dtable[,i]))
}
```

This looks highly inefficient for the data.table package, as we are using a for loop.

What is the most efficient "data.table" way to convert the data type several columns in this fashion, without a for-loop?

Comment: set(dtable, j = i, value = as.character(dtable[[i]])) inside the loop should make it efficient. Alternatively, use lapply(.SD, as.character) together with .SDcols. The person who wrote that legacy code didn't really know what they were doing. They didn't even know the basics of subsetting such as [[.

Comment: Use colClasses when reading in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop. Here is an example

```
data <- mtcars
str(data)
library(data.table)
id.col <- c(1,2,3,8:11)
setDT(data)[, (id.col) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = id.col]
str(data)
```

Comment: Why would you need `str(data)` given `lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = id.col`?

Comment: I used `str(data)` just to see the number of variables to set `id.col` well.

Comment: Ah, I understand now